# How to solve multithreading problem on arrays

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, locking, deadlock

I've been on job interview recently and that was the question on which i got rejected, so it would be veery nice to know how to solve this in future.

At first they've asked me how to solve simple deadlock problem as

```
lock(a) {
    lock(b) {
        // do smth
    }
}

lock(b) {
    lock(a) {
        // do smth
    }
}
```

After I said: just fix the lock order they'd asked next:

Here comes some pseudo-code (because it's not language-relevant and because i don't remember what exactly there was)

```
function void foo(T[] arr) {
    lock(arr[randint(arr.length)]) {
        lock(arr[randint(arr.length)]) {
             // do smth
        }
    }
}

var arr = new arr{...}

async () => {
    foo(arr)
    foo(arr)
}
```

Question is: How to solve this automatically
UPD: this was C# interview, so maybe only this language have tools to solve this (I don't think so, but this should be noted to not cause misunderstanding)

Comment: FYI: This puzzle illustrates how deadlocks happen in real programs. In another variant, the locks are passed in as two arguments to a function. Hint: The solution to the array version is a bit more obvious because each of the locks has it own unique _index_ within the array.

Answer (score -1):

So, I've been searching and asking people for a while, but noone said nothing except "Use thread-safe collections"

Comment: I did not see your question before now, but as Solomon states in the comments, to handle arrays it's easy. Lock on the indexes in ascending order. Thread-safe collections are not the answer here, because thread-safe collections doesn't solve the question you asked. Arrays are perfectly safe to access cross-thread, but if you need to introduce locks around the elements, thread-safe collections won't help you.